# Google App Engine NDB Retrieving Float Property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm sorry if this question has an obvious solution, but I have been trying to search all day!

I have a very simple NDB model:

```
class UserData(ndb.Model):
    value = ndb.FloatProperty
```

Now, I use the following to add an entity if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise, for now I just log it:

```
features = json.loads(self.request.get("features"))
for field in features:
    val = float(features[field])
    key = ndb.Key("user", user, "model", "1", "param", field)
    res = UserData.query(ancestor=key)
    if res.count() > 0:
        param = res.fetch()[0]
        print "currentVal = " + str(param.value)
    else:                                
        newparam = UserData(parent=key)  
        newparam.value = 1.0             
        newparam.put()
```

Adding the values works fine, but the print line outputs the following:

```
currentVal = <class 'google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.FloatProperty'>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field definition is wrong: you need to instantiate the property.

```
class UserData(ndb.Model):
    value = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Comment: OMG I am so stupid. It hurts to admit how long that took me! Thanks very much :-)

Comment: No worries, it's always the little things that are the hardest to spot.